# delayed_job rake jobs:work rails 4 not sending mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, delayed-job

UserMailer with delay method not working in rails 4. As mentioned below, this code doesn't works

```
def welcome_email
  UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(self)
end
```

But when I use below code it works fine.

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
```

I have installed 2 gems, i.e

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Comment: Did you make sure there is a DelayedWorker running?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: where do i need to run DelayedWorker?

Comment: @pulkit21 email is not being sent by the .delay

Comment: @rohit Try running this command **rake jobs:work** to start a job

Comment: @pulkit21 I had tried all that stuff required for delayed_job plugin, but email is been sent

Comment: @rohit run **rails c** and check the **Delayed::Job.all**. If jobs are there in the table or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64989/discussion-between-rohit-and-pulkit21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `ENV` variables to your worker command.
Use this command in your command line:

```
rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=development VARIABLE_1='' VARIABLE_2=''
```